# Add DLL to SharePoint bin folder

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I'm building a SharePoint custom web part.
I need to add a reference in my project to a DLL file. That file doesn't have a strong name and since it's a third party assembly,I can't generate the strong name.

I've been advised to copy the DLL directly to the SharePoint bin folder.

So, where can i find that folder, and after I copy the DLL to that destination, I just need to add as a reference (just like any other file)?

Comment: Yes, the SharePoint bin folder should be under the Project folder. Once added you will need to add the reference.

Comment: And FYI, you may want to create a new folder for 3rd party dll's. This way they can be checked in if you are using any source control. And you can create a reference from your new folder.

Comment: Create a folder where? With that new folder won't I need having the problem with the lack of strong name in the DLL assembly?

Comment: A new folder in your SharePoint project. Name it what you want like ExternalDLLs. Then create a reference to the new dll in that folder. You can then use it in your code just like any other reference.

Comment: But if I do that I believe I'll get the warning (and error when executing) because the name of the assembly is not strong...

Comment: But I'll try it.thank you

Comment: I did all that, even added the references to a mapped sharepoint folder (BIN). Even added the .dll files to the _app_bin folder in the sharepoint but still when i run the web part i get an error...

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before for some sharepoint 2010 webparts projects and when googling I found this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/02/28/how-to-assign-a-strong-name-to-an-unsigned-3rd-party-assembly/), there it is explained how to sign third party assemblies with strong name. Basically you disassemble the dll first with **ILDASM.exe** and then you reassemble with **ILASM.exe** providing a ***.snk** file previously done with **sn.exe**. All this is explained in detail in the given article.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, this is what helped me, although the answer might be a little bit late by now.

- Open wsp package in Visual Studio.
- Go to Advanced Tab
- Click Add and choose the dll
- Set Deployment Target = Web Application
- add additional Safe Controls Entries / class resources

Hit OK and save your changes....

Please note:

- placing dlls in the bin folder is deprecated
- Inform your SP Administrators as they will get a warning during deployment:
  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4118468-44b9-4a1d-81e0-b22f8b0f6f13/deploying-web-application-level-is-throwing-error